# simple question about polynomial over ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I saw a question in the book and question is:
 show that $x^2 -x-1 ∈ Z_3[x]$ is irreducible over $Z_3$. 
    i know how to show polynomial is irreducible but "my question is:"
  is $x^2 -x -1$ is polynomial over $Z_3[x]$ ?  i think no because coeffitents $-1 ∉ Z_3$.

Comment: There is a homomorphism $\Bbb Z[x] \to \Bbb Z_3[x]$, given by reducing coefficients mod $3$. This is how you consider $x^2-x-1$ a polynomial over $\Bbb Z_3$.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2 - x - 1 = x^2 + 2x + 2$. It means you treat it as $x^2+2x+2$ instead.

Comment: is it means we have to reduce coeffitent of polynomial to mod n  in Zn  always?

Comment: Yes,and you always have to reduce it so the coefficients are elements of $Z_n$.

Comment: just have another difficulty with same problem. if the polynomial x^2 - x -1 has root u in some extension say K of Z_3[x] then   "what are the elements of Z_3[u] ?"
  i know that Z_3[u] forms a vector space over Z_3 and have basis {1, u} since degree of x^2 - x -1 is 2.

Comment: Can you post it as a new question?

Comment: ok and thank you so.... much for helping.